# Unable to add the item in array on scan in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am developing an application using **Angular 2**.. In my application I am using **barcode scanner** to scan in the text field and storing those items in the array.

When I scan the item get added to array, but when I scan another item the old item it replace the old value in array.

Below is the piece of code which I am using. Please help me if you see any fix for the weird issue.

```
    import { Component,ViewChild,Input, Output,OnInit,ChangeDetectorRef   } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../common/header.component';
//import { SaleCart } from '../model/SaleCart';
//import * as $ from "jquery";
declare var jQuery: any
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posapp.component.css']


})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Treewalker POS';


  public cartItems = []; 
  public query;
  public filteredList = [];
  public products = [{"id":"3","name":"Pears Soap Original 75gm","sku":"89675432189","price":"32.00","special_price":"32.00","qty":null,"barcode":"89675432189","tax":"5","discount":"0"},{"id":"1","name":"Rin","sku":"1111111111111","price":"11.00","special_price":"11.00","qty":"10.000","barcode":"1111111111111","tax":"5","discount":"0"},{"id":"2","name":"Test 1","sku":"23456","price":"10.00","special_price":"10.00","qty":"10.000","barcode":"23456","tax":"5","discount":"0"}];
  constructor() { 



  }

    ngOnInit() {


  }

  add(item) {

    /* check the items in the json data */
    let flag = false;
    var foodItem = {};
    for (let product of this.products) {
       if(product.barcode == item) {
          flag = true; 
          foodItem['ctr'] = 1;
          foodItem['item'] = product;
          break;
        }
    }

    let localCart = [];
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("cart")){
      localCart =  JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(localCart));
    }
    //console.log("food "+JSON.stringify(this.cart));  
    if(flag && localCart.length) {

      let exist = 0;

      for(let i=0; i < localCart.length; i++) {

        if(localCart[i].item.barcode == item) {

          localCart[i].ctr = parseInt(localCart[i].ctr) + 1; 
          //console.log("@@@@ "+this.cart[i].ctr+" --- "+item);
          exist = 1;

        }
      }
      if(!exist){
        localCart.push(foodItem);
      }
      sessionStorage.setItem("cart",JSON.stringify(localCart));

      //this.barcode = "";
    }else if(flag){

      localCart.push(foodItem);

      sessionStorage.setItem("cart",JSON.stringify(localCart));
    }
    //this.cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));

    //this.itemsCnt = localCart.length;
    //console.log("--- "+this.itemsCnt);
    console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart')));
    //this.onScanProduct.emit(localCart);


}

  filter(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();  
    if (this.query !== ""){

        this.filteredList = this.products.filter(function(el){
            if(el.barcode.toLowerCase() == this.query.toLowerCase()) {

                return el.barcode.toLowerCase() == this.query.toLowerCase();
            }else{
               return el.barcode.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            } 

        }.bind(this));

        /* scanned item will be added to the cart */         
        console.log(this.filteredList.length);
        if(this.filteredList.length > 0 && e.which == 13){

            //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.filteredList));
            for (let product of this.filteredList) {
                //console.log(filter.barcode+"=="+this.query);
                if(product.barcode == this.query) {
                    this.add(product.barcode);
                    jQuery('#barcode').val("");jQuery('#barcode').focus();
                    this.filteredList = [];
                }
            }

        } 

    }else{
        this.filteredList = [];
    }
}



}
```

Below is the html template

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content">

       <form>
         <div class="row">
          <!-- sales item add window -->

          <!-- end --> 

            <div class="col-sm-4">





               <div class="box box-primary">
                   <div class="box-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-9">
                              <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode"  name="barcode" [(ngModel)]="barcode" (ngModelChange)="add($event)"
                              placeholder="Enter item code or scan the barcode" autocomplete="off" />-->
                              <input id="barcode" type="text" class="form-control validate filter-input" name="query" [(ngModel)]="query" (keyup)="filter($event)" placeholder="Enter item code or scan the barcode" autocomplete="off" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                           </div>
                           <div class="suggestions" *ngIf="filteredList.length > 0">
                              <ul>
                                  <li *ngFor="let item of filteredList" >
                                      <a (click)="select(item)" href="javascript:;">{{item.barcode}} {{item.name}}</a>
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                           <div class="col-md-3">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="createnewproduct(newproduct)">New Product</button>
                           </div>

                        </div>

                      </div> 


                    </div> <!-- end of box body -->
                </div>
              </div>         


            </div><!-- end of row -->
           </form>
          </section>



</div>
```

Below is the input field which is being used to **scan the barcode**

```
<input id="barcode" type="text" class="form-control validate filter-input" [(ngModel)]="query" (keyup)="filter()" placeholder="Enter item code or scan the barcode" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using only the function add. I tried to implement in a javascript like in the following code but I am pretty sure you are referencing that object somewhere else and you are changing it. That's my conclusion but I might be wrong.

```
var factoryP = (function(){

    function P() {
        this.cart = [];
        this.products = [{'barcode': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'barcode': 1, 'name': 'b'}]

    }

    function add(item) {

          /* check the items in the json data */
          //console.log("cart length "+JSON.stringify(this.cart));
      let flag = false;
      var foodItem = {};
      for (let product of this.products) {

        if(product.barcode == item) {
                //console.log("check "+item);
          flag = true; 
          foodItem['ctr'] = 1;
          foodItem['item'] = product;
          break;
        }
      }

      if(flag && this.cart.length) {

        let exist = 0;

        for(let i=0; i < this.cart.length; i++) {

          if(this.cart[i].item.barcode == item) {
                //console.log("Same product");
            this.cart[i].ctr = parseInt(this.cart[i].ctr) + 1; 
            exist = 1;

          }
        }
        if(!exist){

          console.log(foodItem);
          this.cart.push(foodItem);
        }

      }else if(flag){
        console.log("step 4 "+item);
        this.cart.push(foodItem);

      }


    }

    P.prototype.add = add;
    return  new P();
  });

instanceP = factoryP();
instanceP.add(1);
instanceP.add(1);
instanceP.add(1);
instanceP.add(2);


console.log(instanceP.cart[0].ctr)
//output 3
instanceP.cart[1].ctr
//output 1
```

Comment: I am using the cart as @Input() cart = []; in the component and it value is being passed to parent  using  this.onScanProduct.emit(this.cart) where I just assign the cart items to parent cart onAdd(items) {
       // console.log("check this put ");
        this.cart = items;
        this.itemsCnt = this.cart.length;
    
  }

Comment: Cuz I can't see that code you have to debug after you push an item and look what happen after you emit.

Comment: I have updated the full code .. here it works fine .. but when I try to include the field in the child it does not work properly ..

Comment: I test your code in my machine and I have to change the select for the add function. I do not understand what field and in what child do you refer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code here. Every time you are initializing the foodItem array with empty array. So whenever code will call add method, it will first empty your foodItem array.

Please check my comment in your code below:

```
add(item) {

       let flag = false;

//Akshay: You need to make your changes here. Initialize your foodItem array out of this scope
       var foodItem = {};
       for (let product of this.products) {
         if(product.barcode == item) {
           //console.log("check "+item);
           flag = true; 
           foodItem['ctr'] = 1;
           foodItem['item'] = product;
           break;
         }
       }
```

Comment: But the thing is my main array is cart which is rendered by the template and the products which get added in cart will display . fooditem is local and holds the current item which we scan and thats why  being used only for that scope only ...